# Backbone.js - Liking a post, code refactoring

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

Right now I'm using this code to Like a post. **I'm Using jQuery methods to change the Like to Unlike and to change the Like count**

View

```
Streaming.Views.StreamsIndex = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click .like-icon': 'post_liked',
  },

  initialize: function(){
    this.model = new Streaming.Models.StreamsIndex();
    this.model.bind('post_likeSuccess', this.post_likeSuccess);
  },

  post_liked: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    current_target = $(event.currentTarget);
    liked_id = current_target.attr("id");
    href = current_target.attr('href');
    this.model.like(href, liked_id); // calls model to send API call for Like
  },

  post_likeSuccess: function(data, liked_id) {
    $("#" + liked_id).attr({
        "href": data.unlike,
        "title": "Unlike",
        "rel": "Unlike",
        "class": "likehead-ico_active" // changing like icon
    });
    //changing like count 
    $("#"+ liked_id+"_count").text(parseInt($("#"+ liked_id+"_count").text()) + 1);
  }
});
```

Model:

```
Streaming.Models.StreamsIndex = Backbone.Model.extend({
  like: function(href, liked_id) {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            self.trigger('post_likeSuccess', data, liked_id);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            self.trigger('post_likeFail', data, liked_id);
            alert("This action was not performed");
        }
    });
  }
});
```

1. Is there a better way I can do this?
2. After liking a post can I change the Like text to unLike, Change the like count in a better way without using jquery?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use jQuery? or just like that you want to try?

Comment: In model you should try to use url form of Backbone-Model rather then using ajax calls. http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url

Comment: I'm not sure if the flow that I have followed is correct. Just wanted to know if there is an alternative way in backbone.

Comment: iCybernetics: Thanks! I will try that!

Comment: As i said, you should used URL form of Backbone.Model instead of Ajax calls in Backbone.Model itself. If you are using Ajax call in Backbone.view then it fine.

Comment: But should I create a model for each event? say like, unlike, comment, delete comment etc.

Comment: See keep one thing in mind. If you are performing any CURD operations on any particular model/collection then you should follow Backbone theory. And if you are only doing single operations like you are only performing one of operation delete / read / update its better to go for Ajax call rather then Backbone theory.

Comment: As said by @Swanand there are some of the code errors and I don't think it would be a good idea for create number of models for each events. You need to find some other way round like parameter passing to url using setParams and getParams...some thing like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with this code. I'll try address them one by one.

1. Looks like your `Streaming.Views.StreamsIndex` has several `posts` in it. It should be broken down into a component views, that are rendered through a collection, so that each model in the collection is bound to a view. You could, maybe call it `Streaming.Views.StreamPost`

   1. Your initialize method would have:

      `this.collection = this.model.posts(); // Or something to this effect`
   2. Your render method would have:

      ```
      // addPost is a function
      // that takes 'post' as a parameter
      // build the corresponding view object
      // and appends it to the posts container

      this.collection.each(this.addPost, this)

      // example of how addPost looks

      var view = new Streaming.Views.StreamPost({model: post});
      this.$('#posts-container').append(view.render().el);
      ```
2. The event listener `'click .like-icon': 'post_liked'` should on the new component view `Streaming.Views.StreamsIndex`, instantiated in the `addPost` above. With this, you don't have to use the ugly `current_target = $(event.currentTarget)` hack. You always do `this.model.get('id')` to get the `id` of the `post`. The thumb rule he is to *not* use jQuery or any other form of raw DOM manipulation when using Backbone. That is what views & templates are for! Adjust your template by putting a little logic (as little as possible) to show something if post is liked, and show something else if post is not liked yet. The job of deciding whether a post is liked or not, is to be done by the `Post` model. I usually write wrapper methods in views that call relevant methods on the model.
3. Instead of using custom events like `post_likeSuccess`, update the state of your model and re-render your view. If you updated your templates like I mentioned above, then re-render would take care of all the DOM manipulation you are doing.